# Input text at the cursor (in any window)

Tags: input, paste

I need to be able to input some text (constant) at the cursor of any window by pressing a defined shortcut (I know this is specific to a window manager, so this isn't part of the question).

I.e. I'm making a comment on a site, want to add my signature, press a shortcut and the signature is pasted at the cursor. This must not be app-specific.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `This must not be app-specific` -> you mean you don't want snippet tool?

Comment: Thanks for responding but I'm not sure what you mean by 'snippet tool'. I want this to work the same way as if typed it myself into the current window at the current position.

Comment: Its a tool that lets you saved any codes, comments, signature, etc. and creates it's shortcut keyword and when you type the word and press TAB(if configured as TAB key completion or ENTER) the signature(for example) will be auto-displayed.

Comment: Do you have a link to it? I'd be interested in taking a look at it.

Comment: my pleasure, i'll provide it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I was hoping for. Happy New Year :)

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AutoKey` from [google code](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/). You should install it from source. Please follow the below instructions after downloading and extracting the source from [here](https://autokey.googlecode.com/files/autokey-0.90.4.tar.gz). For instance you extracted to the Desktop:

```
cd Desktop/autokey-0.90.4/ # could be any version but we'll use this one
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs python-central # important
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc # this command will create new deb files outside autokey source folder
cd ../
sudo dpkg --install autokey-gtk_0.90.4-0_all.deb autokey-common_0.90.4-0_all.deb
```

OR

```
sudo dpkg --install autokey-qt_0.90.4-0_all.deb autokey-common_0.90.4-0_all.deb
```

After running dpkg, there could be another dependency errors, so will have to run another command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now your good to go. Run autokey and configure.

Sample below, you see the folder `My Phrases`, when you press `CTRL+F7` (configured already) you will be prompted options to select like `Addresses, First phrase ...`. It's only up to you how you configure it.

[image]